# How do I disable remote printers using group policy

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, windows, settings

When I configure a new remote desktop connection to connect to servers I often forget to uncheck the option inside of local devices and resources for remote printers.  This creates exceptions in the event log for the server I connect of source: TerminalServices-Printers for the printer drivers I use for PDF document conversion.

I'd love to know if it's possible to disable remote printers by default either on the client remote desktop connection options, or on the server so these exceptions no longer occur.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RDP printer sharing is on by default in remote desktop, unfortunately:

> The printer redirection feature is enabled by default in Windows XP Professional when you enable Remote Desktop. **To disable it, use Terminal Services Group Policies**. Use Remote Desktop Connection to disable printer redirection on an individual computer. On the Local Resources tab, clear the Printers check box.

So, you have to edit the [Terminal Services Group Policy](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Terminal-Services-Group-Policy.html) .. but this requires that the **Group Policy Management Console** be installed. Apparently it is an [add-in for Windows Server 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887&displaylang=en), but an off-by-default [part of the install](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2007/09/08/installing-group-policy-in-windows-server-2008/) for Windows Server 2008.

Apparently you can also use the local Group Policy Editor like so:

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. In the Open box, type mmc, and then click OK.
3. On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.
4. Click Add.
5. Under Available Stand-alone Snap-ins, click **Group Policy**, and then click Add.

The relevant section to edit is [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731963(loband).aspx).

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\
Windows Components\Terminal Services\
Terminal Server\Printer Redirection
```

Comment: Great post. Thank you! Windows Server 2008 is so much better for GPO's than 2003 where you had to add custom files to accomplish GPO for limiting access to removable media.

Answer (score 4):

Within your group policy object, go to Computer Configuration - Windows Components - Terminal Services - Client/Server data redirection - "Do not allow client printer redirection".  Set it to Enabled.

If you don't see the section in your group policy object, you may have to manually add the system.adm template to the policy first.

*Edit: I should also probably add that this group policy should be applied to the server, not on the client.  And you can do it using the local group policy object if the server isn't actually in a domain.

Comment: Thought about this before never did anything about it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 2008 R2 this is under 
Computer Configuration
-> Administrative Templates
-> Windows Components
-> Remote Desktop Services
-> Remote Desktop Session Host
-> Printer Redirection
on the managment console snap in.

Answer (score 0):

For whom may won't touch the GP
at windows 2003 server
run --> tscc.msc

at the connection --> RDP (Properties)
in client setting tab

You can change the way client map it resources to the terminal session